# How to input values and click button with Requests?

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests, beautifulsoup

With the requests module i eventually want to download a song. if you head to youtube-mp3.org, there is one input bar and one convert button. Shortly after the convert is finished there is a download button. Now i want to go throught the process with my python script.

so far i have this:

```
def download_song(song_name):
    import requests

    with requests.Session() as c:
        url = r"http://www.youtube-mp3.org/"
        c.get(url)
```

it barely anything... i have tried to check the documentation on there website. i dont think i need any authentication for any of this. previously i have used requests with bs4 to find links and information on a pages, never tried to put input.

thanks for any help

Comment: Have analyzed the website yet? you can inspect the dom tree with your browser (firefox, chrome for sure, don't know about other browsers).
The convert button is an <input> element in a form, you just have to make a request which matches the <form>'s (action, method)
The download is a link (<a> element), you just have to make a request to the url it points to

Comment: i think i can work with the download link, but the convert button isnew to me. i cant understand it @Pedru

Comment: A starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: i think im getting somewhere. 1 thing i got stuck on is that the form has no name... and from what i read it should submit anything... how does this work? @pedru

Answer (score 2):

## concerning the 'download' link (easy)

Just make a request to the url

## concerning the form (more complicated)

### What the browser does

When you click on a 'submit' button inside a `<form>` element, the browser collects all data from all the `<input>` elements inside the form, in this case it collects content of the text input where you put the url of the video. 
The browser then sends a request to the URL specified in the form's 'action' attribute with the method specified in the form's 'method' attribute .

### The form in question:

```
<form method="get" action="/" id="submit-form">
    <input id="youtube-url" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE" onclick="sAll(this)" autocomplete="off" type="text">
    <div id="btns">
        <input id="submit" value="Convert Video" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

### What you have to do

You have to make a request as if you were a browser. You have the URL of the video you want to convert, now
you have to create an HTTP request to the URL specified in the form (in this case '/' - I think that's relative to the current URL of the page but I'm not sure) with the method specified in the form (in this case GET).
See [the doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) on how to send form-encoded data

Your request to convert a video should look something like this:

```
page_url = 'http://www.youtube-mp3.org/'
video_url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE"
resp = requests.get(page_url, data={'youtube-url': video_url})
```

## EDIT: Extra

In the 'developers tools' of your browser you can capture the HTTP request that your browser sends when you click on 'Convert video', that could help